# Crossfilter: how to remove or filter values from group

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I'm trying to get a group with the sum of values of a csv file, but I want to remove all the zero values.

Example of my csv file:

```
Continents      Function      Value  
South Asia      Function1   
South Asia      Function2     14  
Europe          Function1   
Europe          Function2     12  
Europe          Function3     2
```

I want to get

```
{"key":"Function2","value":26},  
{"key":"Function3","value":2}
```

Here is my code:

```
var ndx = crossfilter( csv );  
var functions = ndx.dimension( function( d )
{
   return d["Function"];
} );  
var functionAmountGroup = functions.group().reduceSum( function ( d )
{
   return d3.format( ".2f" )( d["Value"] );
} );
```

I get

```
{"key":"Function2","value":26},  
{"key":"Function3","value":2},  
{"key":"Function1","value":0}
```

but I want to remove the "Function1" line because of the zero value.

I tried to filter with the value dimension, it's ok

```
var filterValues = ndx.dimension( 
   function( d )
   {
      return d["Value"];
   } ).filter( 
       function( d )
       {
          if( 0 < Math.abs( d ) )
            return d;
       } );
```

That returns me well :

```
{"Continents":"Europe","Function":"Function3","Value":"2"},  
{"Continents":"South Asia","Function":"Function2","Value":"14"},
{"Continents":"Europe","Function":"Function2","Value":"12"}
```

But filterValues is now a dimension, then I don't know how to get a new dimension with "Function" with these filtered result.
Something like

```
filteredValues.dimension( function( d )
        {
            return d["Function"];
        } );
```

which is wrong!

Can someone help me please? I have no more ideas!
Thanks a lot,
vanessa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please create a jsFiddle. I don't believe the code you post does what you say it does, and a working example will solve this problem. Specifically:

```
var filterValues = ndx.dimension( 
   function( d )
   {
      return d["Value"];
   } ).filter( 
       function( d )
       {
          if( 0 < Math.abs( d ) )
            return d;
       } );
```

returns a dimension, not a list of records.

To answer your question: If you do the following, functionAmountGroup.top(Infinity) should give you what you want.

```
var ndx = crossfilter( csv );  
var functions = ndx.dimension( function( d ) {
   return d["Function"];
} );  
var functionAmountGroup = functions.group().reduceSum( function ( d ) {
   return d3.format( ".2f" )( d["Value"] );
} );
var filterValues = ndx.dimension( 
   function( d ) {
      return d["Value"];
   } ).filter( 
       function( d ) {
          if( 0 < Math.abs( d ) )
            return d;
       } );
```

The .filter() call on the new dimension will adjust the functionAmountGroup defined on the other dimension.

You could also just do:

```
var ndx = crossfilter( csv );  
var functions = ndx.dimension( function( d ) {
   return d["Function"];
} );  
var functionAmountGroup = functions.group().reduceSum( function ( d ) {
   return d3.format( ".2f" )( d["Value"] );
} );
functionAmountGroup.top(Infinity).filter( function (d) { return d.value !== 0; } );
```

Edit: This doesn't work. You actually need to create a fake Crossfilter group that is pre-filtered and pass it to dc.js. Like this:

```
var filteredFunctionAmountGroup = {
    all: function () {
        return functionAmountGroup.top(Infinity).filter( function (d) { return d.value !== 0; } );
    }
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/h28hp/17/

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot for your answer !    I tried your code, but it's still not working because at the end, I need a dc group to make a barchart.  I made a jsFiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/vma/h28hp/15/  Thanks again for your help.  vanessa

Comment: Ah, yes, I see what you mean now. This is actually something that dc.js would probably have to add in its API to make it work predictably, unfortunately. In the meantime, I've updated your jsFiddle with a total hack that fakes a Crossfilter group: http://jsfiddle.net/h28hp/17/

Comment: Yeah it's working very well ! thanks so much for this idea, I didn't though a such hack :)